# Add query string to URL redirect

Tags: javascript, redirect

I am trying to use a query string which I can successfully do unless it is a mobile page. What I am doing is checking if it is mobile and redirecting. Is there a way to attach the query string to the redirect url?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[  
    var mobile = (/iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));  
    if (mobile) {  
        document.location = "http://www.xxxxxxx.com/mobile";  
    }  
// ]]></script> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>xxxxxxxxx</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        var total = 0;
        for(var x = 0; x < parameters.length; x++){
            document.getElementById("customerID").value = parameters[x].value;
        }
        document.forms[0].onsubmit = validate;  
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What if some mobile device you didn't mention there navigates your site? I think you are approaching the problem wrong.

Comment: How about: `+ window.location.search` ?

Comment: just add the query string to the URL , whats the issue?

Comment: Would'nt the serverside be a more proper place to do those kind of redirects ?

Comment: You will never capture all the devices. Consider why you need to treat mobile differently and test for that instead. E.g. test for screen size using css media queries or javascript and adjust layout based on that. Try to avoid using redirects which slow down load times on what is already likely to be a slow connection

Comment: The mobile part isn't the issue. This isn't for everybody to use but an in house site. I am encompassing what I need to for the mobile part. I just need the data passed in the query string to be passed on redirect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this might be what you want..

```
var mobile = (/iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));  
if (mobile) {
  window.location = "http://www.xxxxxxx.com/mobile" + window.location.search + window.location.hash;
}
```

I simplified this as window.location.search is either a blank string or starts with ?. Same goes for .hash

If your starting URL was http://www.some.com/entry?id=10 the redirect would be http://www.some.com/mobile?entry?id=10

Same goes for hashes

http://www.some.com/entry?id=10#paragraph2
would redirect to
http://www.some.com/mobile?id=10#paragraph2

If the current URL does not contain either the redirect URL will remain as is.